# keeping a LDAP user logged in with PHP session

Tags: php, session, ldap

UPDATED According to advice below. But still not working. Any help?

My company uses Active Directory LDAP and I'm using adLDAP to authenticate the user to login to this website.

So far, it works.. but every time they visit the page they must login again. The solution to this, I know is sessions. But I can't figure out what to store in the session in order to keep the user logged in.

This is included at the top of my `login.php` page:

auth.php

```
<?php
//include LDAP authenication script
 require_once('LDAP/adLDAP.php');
  $adldap = new adLDAP();
  $username = $_POST['account'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $authUser = $adldap->authenticate($username, $password);
  $userinfo = $adldap->user_info($username, array("*"));
  if ($authUser == true) {
  $_SESSION['LDAP']['login'] = true
  }
?>
```

Also at top of every page I have this:

```
<?php
if (empty('LDAP')) session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['LDAP']['login'] && $_SESSION['LDAP']['login'] !== true) {
header('Location: login.php');
exit; // dont forget the exit here...
}
?>
```

Right now, everytime I visit my index page `index.php` I log in, and I'm redirected to the main page. It works perfectly. But if I refresh the page, I'm asked to login again.

What do I store into a session so I don't have to log in everytime I refresh the page?

I know it starts with:

```
session_start();
```

But I don't know what to store in it?

Answer (score 2):

You should only authenticate/include LDAP on your login page.. 
if success set a $_SESSION['LDAP']['login'] = true;

And check on every page with this.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['LDAP']['login'] && $_SESSION['LDAP']['login'] !== true) {
   header('Location: login.php');
   exit; // dont forget the exit here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I understand your calling your session `LDAP` but why are you using ['login']? Where doe that come from?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand you are setting ['login'] to true, then checking if it's set to true. But how do I set this to true when I login?

Comment: if ($adldap->authenticate($username, $password)) { $_SESSION['LDAP']['login'] = true   }     authenticate will be true i think

Comment: I still don't understand where or how I start the session. This helps me check to see if I'm logged in, but doesn't explain how to use session_start(); to set session.

Comment: you should call session_start() always on the top off a .php file and try to start it this way   "if (empty(session_id)) session_start();"

Comment: I updated above code with what I interpret as how you say I should do it. It doesn't seem to be working for me still so I know it's not correct.  Please advise?

Comment: if (empty('LDAP')) session_start(); should be "if (empty(session_id())) session_start()"

Comment: It doesn't work. Now page won't even load. Thanks for trying though.